# How Can I run/start json-server and live-server using NPM scripts start in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, json-server, npm-live-server

I have a project which has html/css/javascript files, and I want to type the command `npm start` to run [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) and [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server).

I tried this command: `"start": "json-server --watch db.json && live-server"`, but it starts the first command only, and not both.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "testa-npm-live-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json && live-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

IDE: vscode
Node version: v12.18.1
NPM version: 6.14.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run commands in **paralell**. `&&` runs in serial/sequential i.e. second command starts only after first command finishes running.

```
{
  "name": "testa-npm-live-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"json-server --watch db.json\" \"live-server\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Many Thanks to the community of [NodeSchool Campinas](https://nodeschool.io/campinas/) for helping :)

Comment: What directory would `db.json` be in?